# No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt

I create the schedule for school, from GitHub, but I don't khow, what is the problem.
After compiling, I see this message.

> No such or file directory - sqlite3.h

```
#ifndef PMANAGER_H
#define PMANAGER_H
#include <sqlite3.h> /* Version: 3.9.2 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <experimental/filesystem>
#include "../model/event.h"
#include "../model/category.h"
```

Comment: Is SQLite3 installed? Is its development package installed? *Where* is it installed?

Comment: Can you give me the link? I don't know, how to install.

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the section named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: I install the SQlite3 in program folder. But the problem did not dare.

Comment: You are probably missing the headers (which are included in the SDK). If the repo is public, please post it, so we can understand.

Comment: I add to path the sqlite library. Nothing has changed

Comment: https://github.com/echo-devim/kalendar

Answer (score 0):

***Solution 1:***

- First: Download [SQLite3](https://www.sqlite.org/2019/sqlite-amalgamation-3280000.zip) and extract and rename it in such a way as to have `c:\sqlite3\sqlite3.h`
- Then make sure that your `.pro` file contain:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\\sqlite3\\
DEPENDPATH += C:\\sqlite3\\
```

***Solution 2:*** Use `QSqlDatabase` and for that you need to add to your `.pro` file this:

```
QT += sql
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I see the massage: [Makefile] Error 3.

Comment: Which solution did you use ? Are you using Qt Creator?
Please show me you `.pro` file.

Comment: `Assignment needs exactly one word on the left hand side.`

Comment: It is very likely that you wrote your `.pro` incorrectly. For example by missing the line continuation character `\\` in list of files.

Comment: Please copy the content of your .pro file [here](https://pastebin.com/), "Create new paste" then send me the link.

Comment: The `.pro` file is bellow

Comment: Where did you get the error `Assignment needs exactly one word on the left hand side.`? which line?

Comment: `QT       + = sql` this one

Comment: remove the space between + and =.
Or you can just write `QT       += core gui sql`

Comment: `ERROR: 'sqlite3' does not name a type
     sqlite3 *db = NULL;` in pmanager.cpp, class Pmanager private

Comment: I updated the post. I think that you downloaded a wrong package of `SQLite3`. And, i have to notice you that the `GitHub`'s project that you're using it is not intended for `Windows`. if you compile it in `Windows` you have to make a lot of changes.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your help is priceless =)

Comment: Please set the posr as answer for your question.

Comment: For the schedule i will try to find something for you.

Comment: Are you find? :)

Comment: I found some projects: 
1) [This one](https://github.com/sd65/Project-Calendar) you can edit it little bit. 
2) [This one](https://github.com/dmitrytoropchin/excalendarwidget) is just a Calendar (GUI), you can Implement the action your self.
I will try to find better.